# Visual Studio 2013 and Update 2 (Intermittent Build Errors)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When we installed SP2 we started noticing the following when building solutions:

```
ERROR C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2348,5): Task host node exited prematurely. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt. 
ERROR C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2366,7): The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match target type.
```

And then looking at one of the MSBuild_*.failure.txt files I see:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 26072:
=====================
5/20/2014 4:18:22 PM
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Initialize(Int32 capacity)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketReadTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskParameter.ReadITaskItem(INodePacketTranslator translator, ITaskItem& wrappedItem)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskParameter.TranslateITaskItemArray(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskParameter.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskParameter.FactoryForDeserialization(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketReadTranslator.Translate[T](T& value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketReadTranslator.TranslateDictionary[T](Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer, NodePacketValueFactory`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHostConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHostConfiguration.FactoryForDeserialization(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketFactory.PacketFactoryRecord.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketFactory.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, NodePacketType packetType, INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.OutOfProcTaskHostNode.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, NodePacketType packetType, INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeEndpointOutOfProcBase.PacketPumpProc()
===================
```

It seems to happen on the first time we build a solution and then stops happening for awhile and then comes back and then goes away for awhile. Any ideas on how to fix this? I can't be out-of-memory as I am ONLY running VS2013 & a couple of IE instancens on a 64bit system with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: The amount of physical ram and the other apps you're running are irrelevant. Each process has it's own memory and will use virtual memory if necessary. msbuild is a 32-bit process so can address only 4GB of RAM, a good chunk of which is reserved.

Comment: Just a note: Microsoft don't do service packs any more.  It's "Update 2", not "Service Pack 2".

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same.  Additionally, I've also started getting the same intermittent error when using VS2010 to compile the same project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was getting exactly the same behaviour after installing VS 2013 Update 2, but not when compiling directly from inside Visual Studio. I got these errors when using `msbuild` in our separate build scripts (a collection of Windows "bat" files). These scripts were using

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

Luckily, the path to this program is configurable for all of our scripts in a single place (by using some kind of include mechanism). I exchanged it by

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

and now everything seems to be fine. The latter "MSBuild.exe" seems to be a newer version which was installed as part of the "Upgrade 2", the former is the version belonging to .NET framework 4.

I also tried the amd64 version mentioned by @J.J.Hashemi, but it gave me some nasty warnings about the processor architecture of some framework DLLs not matching my target architecture.

Comment: What environment variable did you set to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe' i am having this problem, but i have no env. variables that looks like the one above.

Comment: @DoomStone: I was talking about our custom build scripts, using a custom environment variable defined by myself. If your build scripts contain the path to MSBUILD, you have to change the path in those scripts whereever it occurs.

Comment: @DocBrown -- Your answer clearly has upvotes, so some are understanding it, but it seems to be missing information for people who don't know what you mean by a script file. The path to the program is configurable? Makes sense, but where? I don't see any environment options for my simple VB.NET project. Being forced to change my project to x64 makes my build fail intermittently.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I read the edit, but I don't see where "the path to this program is configurable in our environment in a single place" is. I even checked my system's Environment Variables. I don't see anything to do with MSBuild. I'm probably being really stupid and missing something really simple here.

Comment: @Keith: I meant "environment" in the sense of "build environment" or "development tools environment", not "environment variables". And as I wrote in the comment above, we use a **custom** environment variable for this purpose, you won't find it among your system environment variables, If you get those errors directly when compiling inside VS (which was not the problem I had), is it possible you have two different VS studio versions installed, and your newer VS uses the older msbuild?

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, I have 2010 and 2013 installed, but I'm using 2013 for this project. I get the error compiling from VS (seemingly randomly). My app uses a ton of memory, so I had to swap it to x64. Doing that seems to ahve caused the random build failure. "...MSBuild exists and can be run" and "The GenerateResource task's outputs could not be retrieved from the FilesWritten parameter. Object does not match target type." It references the 12.0 folder though, so I think it's pointing to the correct place.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by replacing C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin with C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64

Comment: Where did you change this value?